# regex word boundaries

Tags: javascript, regex, cpu-word

I am trying to write a regex to match a string with the START of ALL words in a string.

It would be used to lookup a city via the name or the zipcode (in a city and zipcode concatenated string) when the user types one character (or string).

The problem is that it also matches the END of the city (which is unwanted...) 
I am using the following regex :

```
patt = new RegExp('\\b' + searchchar, 'i')
```

eg :

- teststring : "Sint-niklaas (9100)"
- char typed : 's' 
  => unwanted matches **S**int-niklaa**s** (9100) <== problem :-)
  => wanted matches **S**int-niklaas (9100)
- char typed : '9'
  => wanted matches Sint-niklaas (**9**100) <== ok

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan he actually used `\\b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for that:

```
patt = new RegExp('^(?:[^(]+\\()?' + searchchar, 'mi');
```

`^` is an anchor for the start of the string line (with the m modifier). When you enter a letter, since there are only digits inside parenthesis, the optional non-capturing group fails and the letter can only be at the start. When a digit is entered, the optional group succeeds.

Comment: Casimir & Hippolyte. That was exactly what i was looking for! Thanks :)